# I would like to write a nested IF statement in Excel using Dates in multiple cells

Tags: excel, if-statement, multiple-instances, nested

I would like to have A2 = The Output Date:

```
B2 = A2
If B2 ="X"  output Date C2 
If B2 ="X"  and C2="X" output Date D2 
If B2 ="X"  and C2="X" and D2="X" output Date E2

I tried to write the statement as 

     If(B2="X",C2,IF(C2="X",D2,IFD2="X"E2)))
```

Comment: `IFD2="X"E2` should be: `IF(D2="X",E2` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel boolean chaining is sometimes unintuitive, especially so depending on your background. Try this:

```
=IF(B2 = "X", IF(C2 = "X", IF(D2 = "X", E2, D2), C2), "ERROR")
```

The idea is to check the most common condition first, then perform additional checks as they pass. This is roughly equatable to this code:

```
    public string ExcelCheck(string b2, string c2, string d2)
    {
        if (b2 == "X")
        {
            if (c2 == "X")
            {
                if (d2 == "X")
                    return "E2";
                return "D2";
            }
            return "C2";
        }
        return "ERROR";
    }
```

Comment: That worked perfect. If I plug in a date to B2 I get an error message in A2. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Could you explain further?

Comment: A2 is where the date should appear. When I enter "7/18/14" in cell B2; cell A2 says "Error". All the other cells work as they should.

Comment: Try changing "ERROR" in the formula to "B@" and see if that gives you the results you expect.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, sorry, I'm a noob to excel.

Answer (score 0):

You mixed up the sequence.

If you do

```
if(B2 = "X")
   then return C2;

if(B2= "X" && condition2)
   then return D2;

if(B2="X" && condition2 && condition3)
   then return E2;
```

then it will always return C2, because that's the only condition you only ever really test.

You need to do it in this sequence:

```
if(B2="X" && condition2 && condition3)
   then return E2;

if(B2= "X" && condition2)
   then return D2;

if(B2 = "X")
   then return C2;

// TODO: What if none of the conditions match ???
```

So It needs to look like this:

```
=IF(AND(B2="X",C2="X",D2="X"),E2,IF(AND(B2="X",C2="X"),D2,IF(B2="X",C2,"Define a default value please in case all conditions are wrong")))
```

Comment: Doesn't need to be so complicated.

Comment: @Michael: Good catch, your variant is more efficient. Though it isn't really more readable (in terms of non-excel formula).

Comment: If you find a way to produce readable excel formulas, let me know! :) Named ranges and Alt-Enter are my best friends there, but they only go so far.